# relative path too long when absolute path is not (which leads to errors in certain functions)

Tags: r, path

I have set up a certain relative path in one of my scripts. E.g. like below:

```
starting_dir <- "C:/Users/USER/long folder name 1/long folder name 2/"
setwd(starting_dir)
```

From this path I want to navigate around a bit to save some files in folder some levels above (and down again), e.g. like:

```
folder_change <- "../long folder name test/"
file_name <- "very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong name.txt"
```

If I glue that together, it would give me the following ABSOLUTE path:

```
normalizePath(paste0(folder_change, file_name))

"C:\\Users\\USER\\long folder name 1\\long folder name test\\very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong name.txt"
```

(Note: it will give you a warning because the file itself does not yet exist, but we can ignore that for now.)

And running `nchar()` around that path gives me a length of 237 characters, which is still below Windows' limit of 260 characters.

However, if I increase the file name by just one character (note: it might be more or less characters for you depending on how long your USER name in the path is!), then the path would not be a valid Windows path anymore and it would give me a non-working path

```
file_name <- "very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong nameX.txt"

normalizePath(paste0(folder_change, file_name))
```

This would lead to the following output (not how it stops showing the the full beginning of the path):

```
[1] "../long folder name test/very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong nameX.txt"
```

along with a warning `file or extension cannot be found`.

So specifiying the path in absolute terms works, doing it with relatives paths does not.

The problem is that I run a few function where I glue together a relative path, and these error because the relative path is not valid.

I'm confused about this behaviour, because the actual path is valid and works.

What can I do about it?